# Java 1.7 - CMS kicks in before CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction is reached

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

We have a 1.7.0_151-b00 JVM that started doing continuous CMS cycles even though the CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction was not reached.

I am trying to understand why the JVM started doing CMS before reaching CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction.

The JVM command line is as follows:

```
CommandLine flags: -XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:GCLogFileSize=3145728 -XX:InitialHeapSize=7505707008 -XX:MaxHeapSize=7505707008 -XX:MaxNewSize=3221225472 -XX:MaxPermSize=536870912 -XX:NewSize=3221225472 -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:OldPLABSize=16 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:PermSize=536870912 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:SurvivorRatio=30 -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:+UseParNewGC
```

Here is a sample of the GC log:

```
2019-03-05T23:50:16.123-0500: 181182.324: [GC2019-03-05T23:50:16.123-0500: 181182.324: [ParNew: 2981168K->35897K(3047424K), 0.0598380 secs] 5745339K->2800067K(7231488K), 0.0600900 secs] [Times: user=0.14 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
2019-03-05T23:59:05.298-0500: 181711.499: [GC2019-03-05T23:59:05.298-0500: 181711.499: [ParNew: 2985017K->38413K(3047424K), 0.0750150 secs] 5749187K->2802583K(7231488K), 0.0752680 secs] [Times: user=0.18 sys=0.00, real=0.07 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:00:49.806-0500: 181816.007: [GC2019-03-06T00:00:49.806-0500: 181816.007: [ParNew: 2956247K->98304K(3047424K), 0.0743290 secs] 5720417K->2899027K(7231488K), 0.0745400 secs] [Times: user=0.28 sys=0.00, real=0.07 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:00:53.260-0500: 181819.461: [GC2019-03-06T00:00:53.260-0500: 181819.461: [ParNew: 2989572K->98304K(3047424K), 0.3472730 secs] 5790295K->3385821K(7231488K), 0.3475250 secs] [Times: user=1.30 sys=0.00, real=0.35 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:00:53.615-0500: 181819.816: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 3287517K(4184064K)] 3444116K(7231488K), 0.0111440 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:00:53.626-0500: 181819.827: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-03-06T00:00:54.091-0500: 181820.292: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.461/0.465 secs] [Times: user=1.76 sys=0.08, real=0.46 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:00:54.091-0500: 181820.292: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:00:54.097-0500: 181820.298: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.006/0.006 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:00:54.097-0500: 181820.298: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2019-03-06T00:00:59.187-0500: 181825.388: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.771/5.090 secs] [Times: user=1.67 sys=0.02, real=5.09 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:00:59.189-0500: 181825.390: [GC[YG occupancy: 1027396 K (3047424 K)]2019-03-06T00:00:59.189-0500: 181825.390: [GC2019-03-06T00:00:59.189-0500: 181825.390: [ParNew (promotion failed): 1027396K->971394K(3047424K), 0.0694260 secs] 4314914K->4290206K(7231488K), 0.0695910 secs] [Times: user=0.23 sys=0.00, real=0.07 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:00:59.259-0500: 181825.460: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0075580 secs]2019-03-06T00:00:59.266-0500: 181825.467: [weak refs processing, 0.0134090 secs]2019-03-06T00:00:59.280-0500: 181825.481: [scrub string table, 0.0049400 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 3318812K(4184064K)] 4290206K(7231488K), 0.0960510 secs] [Times: user=0.28 sys=0.00, real=0.10 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:00:59.285-0500: 181825.486: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:00.981-0500: 181827.182: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 1.695/1.695 secs] [Times: user=1.69 sys=0.01, real=1.69 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:00.981-0500: 181827.182: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:00.996-0500: 181827.197: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.015/0.015 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:02.998-0500: 181829.199: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1453847K(4184064K)] 2433271K(7231488K), 0.0172810 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:03.016-0500: 181829.217: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:03.287-0500: 181829.488: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.271/0.271 secs] [Times: user=1.08 sys=0.00, real=0.27 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:03.287-0500: 181829.488: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:03.300-0500: 181829.501: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.012/0.013 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:03.300-0500: 181829.501: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:03.300-0500: 181829.501: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:03.300-0500: 181829.501: [GC[YG occupancy: 979423 K (3047424 K)]2019-03-06T00:01:03.300-0500: 181829.501: [GC2019-03-06T00:01:03.301-0500: 181829.502: [ParNew: 979423K->979423K(3047424K), 0.0000290 secs] 2433271K->2433271K(7231488K), 0.0001210 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:03.301-0500: 181829.502: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0097700 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:03.310-0500: 181829.511: [weak refs processing, 0.0035040 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:03.314-0500: 181829.515: [scrub string table, 0.0044180 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 1453847K(4184064K)] 2433271K(7231488K), 0.0180610 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:03.319-0500: 181829.520: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:03.761-0500: 181829.962: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.442/0.442 secs] [Times: user=0.45 sys=0.00, real=0.44 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:03.761-0500: 181829.962: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:03.768-0500: 181829.969: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.007/0.007 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:05.770-0500: 181831.971: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1162451K(4184064K)] 2151266K(7231488K), 0.0208420 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:05.791-0500: 181831.992: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:06.068-0500: 181832.269: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.277/0.277 secs] [Times: user=1.11 sys=0.00, real=0.28 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:06.068-0500: 181832.269: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:06.074-0500: 181832.275: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.006/0.006 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:06.074-0500: 181832.275: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:06.074-0500: 181832.275: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:06.075-0500: 181832.276: [GC[YG occupancy: 988815 K (3047424 K)]2019-03-06T00:01:06.075-0500: 181832.276: [GC2019-03-06T00:01:06.075-0500: 181832.276: [ParNew: 988815K->988815K(3047424K), 0.0000250 secs] 2151266K->2151266K(7231488K), 0.0001110 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:06.075-0500: 181832.276: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0143500 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:06.090-0500: 181832.291: [weak refs processing, 0.0043930 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:06.094-0500: 181832.295: [scrub string table, 0.0051840 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 1162451K(4184064K)] 2151266K(7231488K), 0.0243670 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:06.101-0500: 181832.302: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:06.718-0500: 181832.919: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.617/0.617 secs] [Times: user=0.62 sys=0.00, real=0.62 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:06.718-0500: 181832.919: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:06.725-0500: 181832.926: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.008/0.008 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:08.727-0500: 181834.928: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1162240K(4184064K)] 2152208K(7231488K), 0.0206780 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:08.748-0500: 181834.949: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:09.014-0500: 181835.215: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.266/0.266 secs] [Times: user=1.05 sys=0.00, real=0.27 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:09.014-0500: 181835.215: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:09.021-0500: 181835.222: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.006/0.006 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:09.021-0500: 181835.222: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:09.021-0500: 181835.222: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:09.021-0500: 181835.222: [GC[YG occupancy: 989968 K (3047424 K)]2019-03-06T00:01:09.021-0500: 181835.222: [GC2019-03-06T00:01:09.022-0500: 181835.223: [ParNew: 989968K->989968K(3047424K), 0.0000250 secs] 2152208K->2152208K(7231488K), 0.0001120 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:09.022-0500: 181835.223: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0133410 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:09.035-0500: 181835.236: [weak refs processing, 0.0039190 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:09.039-0500: 181835.240: [scrub string table, 0.0047490 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 1162240K(4184064K)] 2152208K(7231488K), 0.0223870 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:09.044-0500: 181835.245: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:09.310-0500: 181835.511: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.266/0.266 secs] [Times: user=0.27 sys=0.00, real=0.26 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:09.310-0500: 181835.511: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:09.317-0500: 181835.518: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.007/0.007 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:11.319-0500: 181837.520: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1162240K(4184064K)] 2159518K(7231488K), 0.0224950 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:11.342-0500: 181837.543: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:11.611-0500: 181837.812: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.270/0.270 secs] [Times: user=1.08 sys=0.00, real=0.27 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:11.611-0500: 181837.812: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:11.619-0500: 181837.820: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.007/0.007 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:11.619-0500: 181837.820: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:11.619-0500: 181837.820: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:11.620-0500: 181837.821: [GC[YG occupancy: 997278 K (3047424 K)]2019-03-06T00:01:11.620-0500: 181837.821: [GC2019-03-06T00:01:11.620-0500: 181837.821: [ParNew: 997278K->997278K(3047424K), 0.0000260 secs] 2159518K->2159518K(7231488K), 0.0001100 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:11.620-0500: 181837.821: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0157150 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:11.635-0500: 181837.836: [weak refs processing, 0.0038150 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:11.639-0500: 181837.840: [scrub string table, 0.0044660 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 1162240K(4184064K)] 2159518K(7231488K), 0.0243440 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:11.644-0500: 181837.845: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:11.896-0500: 181838.097: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.251/0.251 secs] [Times: user=0.26 sys=0.00, real=0.25 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:11.896-0500: 181838.097: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:11.903-0500: 181838.104: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.007/0.007 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:13.904-0500: 181840.105: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1162240K(4184064K)] 2161535K(7231488K), 0.0232400 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:13.928-0500: 181840.129: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:14.187-0500: 181840.388: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.259/0.259 secs] [Times: user=1.02 sys=0.00, real=0.26 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:14.187-0500: 181840.388: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:14.195-0500: 181840.397: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.008/0.008 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:14.196-0500: 181840.397: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:14.196-0500: 181840.397: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:14.196-0500: 181840.397: [GC[YG occupancy: 999294 K (3047424 K)]2019-03-06T00:01:14.197-0500: 181840.398: [GC2019-03-06T00:01:14.197-0500: 181840.398: [ParNew: 999294K->999294K(3047424K), 0.0000260 secs] 2161535K->2161535K(7231488K), 0.0001160 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:14.197-0500: 181840.398: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0161250 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:14.213-0500: 181840.414: [weak refs processing, 0.0040860 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:14.217-0500: 181840.418: [scrub string table, 0.0047250 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 1162240K(4184064K)] 2161535K(7231488K), 0.0253240 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:14.222-0500: 181840.423: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:14.483-0500: 181840.684: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.261/0.261 secs] [Times: user=0.27 sys=0.00, real=0.26 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:14.483-0500: 181840.684: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:14.490-0500: 181840.691: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.007/0.007 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:16.492-0500: 181842.693: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1162238K(4184064K)] 2170926K(7231488K), 0.0266030 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:16.519-0500: 181842.720: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:16.809-0500: 181843.010: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.290/0.290 secs] [Times: user=1.16 sys=0.00, real=0.29 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:16.809-0500: 181843.010: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:16.814-0500: 181843.015: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.006/0.006 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:16.815-0500: 181843.016: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:16.815-0500: 181843.016: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:16.815-0500: 181843.016: [GC[YG occupancy: 1008688 K (3047424 K)]2019-03-06T00:01:16.815-0500: 181843.016: [GC2019-03-06T00:01:16.815-0500: 181843.016: [ParNew: 1008688K->1008688K(3047424K), 0.0000270 secs] 2170926K->2170926K(7231488K), 0.0001070 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:16.815-0500: 181843.016: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0205190 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:16.836-0500: 181843.037: [weak refs processing, 0.0038010 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:16.840-0500: 181843.041: [scrub string table, 0.0043700 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 1162238K(4184064K)] 2170926K(7231488K), 0.0290180 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:16.844-0500: 181843.045: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:17.098-0500: 181843.299: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.253/0.253 secs] [Times: user=0.26 sys=0.00, real=0.25 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:17.098-0500: 181843.299: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:17.105-0500: 181843.306: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.007/0.007 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:19.107-0500: 181845.308: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1162238K(4184064K)] 2172118K(7231488K), 0.0263560 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:19.134-0500: 181845.335: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:19.396-0500: 181845.597: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.263/0.263 secs] [Times: user=1.05 sys=0.00, real=0.27 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:19.396-0500: 181845.597: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:19.402-0500: 181845.603: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.006/0.006 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:19.403-0500: 181845.604: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:19.403-0500: 181845.604: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:19.403-0500: 181845.604: [GC[YG occupancy: 1009880 K (3047424 K)]2019-03-06T00:01:19.403-0500: 181845.604: [GC2019-03-06T00:01:19.403-0500: 181845.604: [ParNew: 1009880K->1009880K(3047424K), 0.0000240 secs] 2172118K->2172118K(7231488K), 0.0001030 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:19.403-0500: 181845.604: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0469840 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:19.450-0500: 181845.651: [weak refs processing, 0.0041000 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:19.455-0500: 181845.656: [scrub string table, 0.0045030 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 1162238K(4184064K)] 2172118K(7231488K), 0.0559270 secs] [Times: user=0.19 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:19.459-0500: 181845.660: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:19.711-0500: 181845.912: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.251/0.251 secs] [Times: user=0.25 sys=0.00, real=0.25 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:19.711-0500: 181845.912: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:19.718-0500: 181845.919: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.007/0.007 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:21.720-0500: 181847.921: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1162238K(4184064K)] 2187866K(7231488K), 0.0321750 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:21.753-0500: 181847.954: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:22.010-0500: 181848.211: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.257/0.257 secs] [Times: user=1.03 sys=0.00, real=0.26 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:22.010-0500: 181848.211: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:22.018-0500: 181848.219: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.008/0.009 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:22.018-0500: 181848.219: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:22.018-0500: 181848.219: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:22.019-0500: 181848.220: [GC[YG occupancy: 1025628 K (3047424 K)]2019-03-06T00:01:22.019-0500: 181848.220: [GC2019-03-06T00:01:22.019-0500: 181848.220: [ParNew: 1025628K->1025628K(3047424K), 0.0000260 secs] 2187866K->2187866K(7231488K), 0.0001080 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:22.019-0500: 181848.220: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0234820 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:22.043-0500: 181848.244: [weak refs processing, 0.0038410 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:22.047-0500: 181848.248: [scrub string table, 0.0045660 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 1162238K(4184064K)] 2187866K(7231488K), 0.0322360 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:22.052-0500: 181848.253: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:22.293-0500: 181848.494: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.241/0.241 secs] [Times: user=0.24 sys=0.00, real=0.24 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:22.293-0500: 181848.494: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:22.300-0500: 181848.501: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.007/0.007 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:24.302-0500: 181850.503: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1162213K(4184064K)] 2189000K(7231488K), 0.0296210 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:24.331-0500: 181850.532: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:24.597-0500: 181850.798: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.265/0.265 secs] [Times: user=1.06 sys=0.00, real=0.27 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:24.597-0500: 181850.798: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:24.603-0500: 181850.804: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.006/0.006 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:24.603-0500: 181850.804: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:24.603-0500: 181850.804: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:24.604-0500: 181850.805: [GC[YG occupancy: 1026789 K (3047424 K)]2019-03-06T00:01:24.604-0500: 181850.805: [GC2019-03-06T00:01:24.604-0500: 181850.805: [ParNew: 1026789K->1026789K(3047424K), 0.0000260 secs] 2189002K->2189002K(7231488K), 0.0001030 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:24.604-0500: 181850.805: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0237750 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:24.628-0500: 181850.829: [weak refs processing, 0.0038520 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:24.631-0500: 181850.832: [scrub string table, 0.0045490 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 1162213K(4184064K)] 2189002K(7231488K), 0.0325080 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:24.636-0500: 181850.837: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:24.886-0500: 181851.087: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.250/0.250 secs] [Times: user=0.25 sys=0.00, real=0.25 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:24.886-0500: 181851.087: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:24.893-0500: 181851.094: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.007/0.007 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:26.895-0500: 181853.096: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1162213K(4184064K)] 2198393K(7231488K), 0.0433240 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:26.939-0500: 181853.140: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:27.209-0500: 181853.410: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.270/0.270 secs] [Times: user=1.08 sys=0.00, real=0.27 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:27.210-0500: 181853.411: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:27.216-0500: 181853.417: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.006/0.006 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:27.216-0500: 181853.417: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:27.216-0500: 181853.417: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:27.217-0500: 181853.418: [GC[YG occupancy: 1036180 K (3047424 K)]2019-03-06T00:01:27.217-0500: 181853.418: [GC2019-03-06T00:01:27.217-0500: 181853.418: [ParNew: 1036180K->1036180K(3047424K), 0.0000270 secs] 2198393K->2198393K(7231488K), 0.0001210 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:27.217-0500: 181853.418: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0518560 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:27.269-0500: 181853.470: [weak refs processing, 0.0048580 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:27.274-0500: 181853.475: [scrub string table, 0.0044990 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 1162213K(4184064K)] 2198393K(7231488K), 0.0616180 secs] [Times: user=0.21 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:27.279-0500: 181853.480: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:27.528-0500: 181853.729: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.250/0.250 secs] [Times: user=0.25 sys=0.00, real=0.25 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:27.528-0500: 181853.729: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:27.535-0500: 181853.736: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.007/0.007 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:29.537-0500: 181855.738: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1162213K(4184064K)] 2199544K(7231488K), 0.0343370 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:29.572-0500: 181855.773: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:29.833-0500: 181856.034: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.262/0.262 secs] [Times: user=1.04 sys=0.00, real=0.26 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:29.834-0500: 181856.035: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:29.839-0500: 181856.040: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.006/0.006 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:29.839-0500: 181856.040: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:29.839-0500: 181856.040: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:29.840-0500: 181856.041: [GC[YG occupancy: 1037331 K (3047424 K)]2019-03-06T00:01:29.840-0500: 181856.041: [GC2019-03-06T00:01:29.840-0500: 181856.041: [ParNew: 1037331K->1037331K(3047424K), 0.0000250 secs] 2199544K->2199544K(7231488K), 0.0000990 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:29.840-0500: 181856.041: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0302710 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:29.870-0500: 181856.071: [weak refs processing, 0.0046400 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:29.875-0500: 181856.076: [scrub string table, 0.0065020 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 1162213K(4184064K)] 2199544K(7231488K), 0.0417850 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:29.882-0500: 181856.083: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:30.362-0500: 181856.563: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.480/0.480 secs] [Times: user=0.53 sys=0.02, real=0.48 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:30.362-0500: 181856.563: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:30.369-0500: 181856.570: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.007/0.007 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:32.371-0500: 181858.572: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1162213K(4184064K)] 2207344K(7231488K), 0.0354480 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:32.406-0500: 181858.607: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:32.672-0500: 181858.873: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.265/0.265 secs] [Times: user=1.04 sys=0.00, real=0.26 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:32.672-0500: 181858.873: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:32.678-0500: 181858.879: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.006/0.006 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:32.678-0500: 181858.879: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:32.678-0500: 181858.879: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:32.679-0500: 181858.880: [GC[YG occupancy: 1045131 K (3047424 K)]2019-03-06T00:01:32.679-0500: 181858.880: [GC2019-03-06T00:01:32.679-0500: 181858.880: [ParNew: 1045131K->1045131K(3047424K), 0.0000250 secs] 2207344K->2207344K(7231488K), 0.0001250 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:32.679-0500: 181858.880: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0402310 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:32.719-0500: 181858.920: [weak refs processing, 0.0039050 secs]2019-03-06T00:01:32.723-0500: 181858.924: [scrub string table, 0.0042770 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 1162213K(4184064K)] 2207344K(7231488K), 0.0487640 secs] [Times: user=0.16 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:32.728-0500: 181858.929: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:32.970-0500: 181859.171: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.242/0.242 secs] [Times: user=0.25 sys=0.00, real=0.24 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:32.970-0500: 181859.171: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:32.977-0500: 181859.178: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.007/0.007 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:34.978-0500: 181861.179: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1162212K(4184064K)] 2208544K(7231488K), 0.0351780 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:35.014-0500: 181861.215: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:35.289-0500: 181861.490: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.276/0.276 secs] [Times: user=1.07 sys=0.00, real=0.28 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:35.289-0500: 181861.490: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:35.296-0500: 181861.497: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.007/0.007 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:35.297-0500: 181861.498: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2019-03-06T00:01:35.297-0500: 181861.498: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-06T00:01:35.297-0500: 181861.498: [GC[YG occupancy: 1048419 K (3047424 K)]2019-03-06T00:01:35.297-0500: 181861.498: [GC2019-03-06T00:01:35.297-0500: 181861.498: [ParNew: 1048419K->1048419K(3047424K), 0.0000270 secs] 2210632K->2210632K(7231488K), 0.0001120 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your old space occupancy at 78% for first initial mark event, so JVM behaves in compliance with CMS options below.

```
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
```

Take a closer lookup at line

```
03-06T00:00:53.615-0500: 181819.816: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 3287517K(4184064K)] 3444116K(7231488K), 0.0111440 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

Occupancy is calculated for **old space** only. Your old space utilization is 3287517K out of 4184064K.

Comment: Note: if it didn't do this you could have CMS fail to start even though the old gen is full. +1

Comment: Actually I am not concerned so much about the first CMS than about the other ones. For instance, the second CMS kicked in at 35% occupancy: `[GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 3287517K(4184064K)] 3444116K(7231488K), 0.0111440 secs]`. I see no reason for the bunch of CMS that occurred after the 1st one.

Comment: I am adding the gceasy report here: https://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMTkvMDMvNy8tLWdjLmxvZy4wLmN1cnJlbnQtLTAtMTEtMTc=&channel=WEB The report shows clearly that the old gen usage is pretty low when it keeps doing CMS.

Comment: @befo88 indeed other collections are started at lower occupancy. Another trigger for CMS could PermGen size. Unfortunately PermGen size is not logged. You can use any JMX based monitoring tool to very PermGen size.

Comment: @AlexeyRagozin Max Permgen is set to 512 MB. Its usage was 159 MB before CMS started to run continuously. On the last CMS run, it went down to 151 MB. So I don't think that Permgen triggered the CMS loop.

Comment: @befo88 I'm out of ideas. CMS shouldn't behave this way.